# Joining column for multiple tables

Tags: sql, select, join, union

I am trying to extract two same-data-type columns from two different tables using one query. NOTE: Accounts attribute length in both table varies. Union can't work here because number of columns are (in reality) different in both tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TABLE_A` (
  `ID_TABLE_A` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ACCOUNT` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `SALES` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TABLE_A`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TABLE_B` (
  `ID_TABLE_B` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ACOUNT` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
  `SALES` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TABLE_B`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Requirement:(I know this can't be right but just to demonstrate a partial picture)

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNTS,
    SALES
FROM
TABLE_A, TABLE_B
```

Result:

```
---------------
|accounts|sales|
| 2854 |52500  |
| 6584 |54645  | 
| 54782| 5624  |
| 58496|46259  |
| 56958| 6528  |
---------------
```

Comment: Please reforrmat your CREATE TABLE statements, such that all of them are code, and put one attribute per line

Comment: "In reality" the number of columns are different, but in your example they are not.  You will probably need a temp table for this - pretty crazy use case "in reality" anyhow.

Comment: @SteveHarris, actual number of tables are 5; with a number of columns varying from 30 to 40. In order to avoid confusion [didn't want to list irrelevant information], I wanted a help where exactly I felt stuck. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the union of two tables that are not union-compatible, then make them union-compatible:

```
(SELECT 
    ACCOUNTS,
    SALES
FROM
TABLE_A) UNION ALL
(SELECT 
    ACCOUNTS,
    SALES
FROM TABLE_B)
```

I put the `UNION ALL` based on the assumption that you would like to keep duplicates.  If you would like the output to be duplicate-free, replace it with `UNION`.

Comment: Worked like a charm MANN. Thanks for a prompt help.